# How to Loop on a string and edit it?

Tags: c#, string, loops

```
string x = "1. hello world";
```

I want to loop on this string and delete characters from so that 
x= "hello world"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make things more clear. What you exactly want?. If you want to remove "1. " then you can use replace function (suggested by wudzik ) or you can also use substring method or string.Format.

Comment: Mmm... and what is wrong with "x = x.Substring(3);"? Why do you need iterate in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Linq `Where()`:

```
string x12 = "1. hello world";

var output= new String(x12.Where(xy => Char.IsLetter(xy) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(xy)).ToArray()).TrimStart();
```

### OUTPUT:

> "hello world"

Comment: It will output `" hello world"`

Comment: we can do ``TrimStart()``

Comment: You should do it for this matter

Answer (score 0):

A simple replace as wudzik suggested will provide you with the output you demo'd, however to answer the question of "how to loop a string and...", you can do the following

```
var myString = "1. Hello world";
foreach(var character in myString )
{
   //perform character operation here
}
```

or you can use linq

```
var newString = myString.Select(c => /*perform character operation here, ie. c.ToString()*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex:

```
string str = "1. Hello world";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b[A-z ]+");
Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(str));
```